# How do I add "id" to script declaration

Tags: javascript

In the example below, the loaded script will appear in the 'head' with a plain 'script' tag but how do I add an id into the declaration so the result is something like 'script id="my-script"'

```
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
    window.event("domready", function() {
        alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration");
    });
');
```

Answer (score 3):

JDocument has a method for inserting arbitrary characters into the head tag. People usually use it for meta tags etc. It's down the bottom of this page:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addCustomTag( '<script id="my-script">window.event("domready", function() { alert("An inline JavaScript Declaration"); });</script>' );
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you.  I'll give this a try.  Cheers.